# Firebase SSL and Subdomains

Tags: firebase, ssl, ssl-certificate, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

So I was using Google cloud buckets to host my site, I figured out SSL Is impossible doing that so I tried app engine and that just got really complicated really fast so I tried firebase and it seems the best, however I have my main site (https://example.com) and my development build of the site with an auth login for me and my devs (https://staging.example.com). I have 2 different firebase projects one for the main site and another for the subdomain, however I first connected the subdomain one and it got an SSL cert and said connected in like 2 seconds, however I did the same for my main site and it's been stuck on pending all day now. I read somewhere that it can't do a subdomain and a normal site because of some SNI thing but if you can't enable SSL on a domain and a subdomain that's a pretty bad system imo. I use Google Domains for my domain and there are A records for the normal domain and subdomain pointing to firebase.

Thanks to anyone with any clarification.

Comment: It can take upto 24hours for it to be provisioned. Make sure you flush your dns cache and try in 24hours. It would also be helpful if you can share the dns records you've set and the firebase console too. I have 2 projects one with a root domain and one with a subdomain no issues.

Comment: Did you get it figured out? Please update and resolve if it was just to wait for DNS propagation. Otherwise, if you're still stuck, what else have you tried. It shouldn't be any problem with main and sub domain. I often use a staging/dev domain under apex domain for Firebase hosted projects.

Comment: @DennisAlund hey ya sorry it was resolved I was just confused as to why one certificate took literal seconds and the other one took almost a day so I thought something was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I just had to wait for the certificate to be made, I was just confused as to why one domain took seconds to make it and the subdomain took almost a day so I thought something was wrong.